# Slipping by BTs undetected

Tags: death-stranding

How does one sneak by these things undetected? No matter what strategy I try they constantly catch me as they are plentiful and teleport randomly. You can't go around one because there's invariably more so just going for the boss battle and running in the original direction seems to be the answer.

Is there some trick to bypassing these? I haven't been able to sneak by undetected not even one time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, it is possible to avoid them entirely for most of the game, basically only dealing with them when the plot forces you into a scripted encounter.  Though the game kind of assumes you failed to do so several times along the way, and picked up on certain things as a result, which can make the solution to a certain plot obstacle later on a near moon-logic mystery.

The other two current answers detail the basic idea of how to use your BB+Odradek to detect and circumvent BT's, as well as a vehicle escape trick for that rare situation where the terrain is actually suitable enough for one in the first place (note that you won't encounter BTs on roads, so once you can start building up roads that's one way to help you ignore them). I'll note that in my experience, on the PS4, you can simply stop moving briefly for the nearby BTs to become visible, so you can look around to help plot your movements or, eventually, pre-emptive attacks.  And don't forget that Sam has a stealth/sneak movement mode!  Walking normally or running will make you an easy target for BTs; sneaking around them generally requires that you sneak.

Another trick to avoiding them is...well, to avoid them.  Mountain goat and climb your way around the region in question, or otherwise through portions of the region not really populated with BTs due to slopes.  For the most part the BT's only spawn in the more easily accessed and flatter paths, leaving the crazy climbing paths with few to no spawns.  It's not a surefire way (I did it quite a lot, so know its shortcomings well), and more than once I climbed myself into a spot where I basically couldn't proceed further from.  Either because I'd invariably slip down a slope, or experience a great fall, both, or just ran out of ladders or what have you to get up or down the next impasse.  At which point you may be forced into more traditional sneaking.  This is part of the tradeoffs you make on your delivery routes: the easier, flatter routes are likely to be populated with BTs and Mules, whereas the annoying rocky outcropping that's in the way of a beeline route has few to none of them.  It's up to you to decide if the potential combat encounters are a bigger slowdown and problem than the mountaineering alternative, and which ones you have the resources on hand for.

Answer (score 4):

#### Hold your breath while moving.

As long as you don't get too close, BTs will detect you by your breathing only.

Additionally, as long as you're in BT territory (and as long as BB is in good shape), your [Odradek](https://deathstranding.fandom.com/wiki/Odradek) will always point towards the closest BT. Simply keep moving forward until the Odradek is pointing forward. When it does, use its scan feature to see where the BT is, and change course to avoid it.

If you need to breathe, just stop moving. BTs are much less likely to detect your breathing while you're staying still. Just make sure you're not too close to a BT when you do so. Your Odradek will start moving frantically if you're too close to a BT.

This will allow you to quickly get through BT territory undetected.

As you progress through the game, you'll gain the ability to stealthily kill BTs. This will allow you to get through BT territory *even faster* undetected.

Like before, hold your breath while moving, but keep moving even if your Odradek points forward. Pay attention to your screen for a prompt to kill the BT, and immediately press the associated button if it appears on screen. With proper timing, Sam will kill the BT even before it notices him. Even if you're slightly late, Sam will still kill the BT before it manages to grab him. This won't alert the other BTs. Feel free to take a break and breathe after killing a BT.

---

#### Just drive

When you gain access to vehicles, you'll be able to completely ignore BTs as long as you have enough battery.

Simply drive through BT territory without worrying about them. The BT will most likely catch you, and when they do, your vehicle will be stuck in the tar. When this happens, immediately use your Boost and don't let go. Your vehicle will eventually manage to get out of the tar before the BT can get ahold of Sam.

Keep in mind that boosting drains your battery faster than driving, so if you're low on battery, build a generator or otherwise find a way to recharge before crossing BT territory.

Also keep in mind that while this strategy works very well, it is not 100% reliable. Very rarely, the BT may succeed in dragging Sam out of his vehicle before he gets unstuck. The vehicle will then sink in the tar and become unavailable until you either defeat the boss, or escape from the BT territory. Cargo contained within the vehicle will be spread on the ground around the vehicle, so don't forget to pick it all up before leaving.

Comment: In my experience on the PS4 at least, you don't have to activate the Odradek to see the BTs.  Simply ceasing to move for a short time will cause nearby ones to become visible, allowing you to just look around and plot some movement in advance.  Or, deep enough into the game, destroy them with weapons.

Answer (score 2):

You can use you scanner called [Odradek](https://deathstranding.fandom.com/wiki/Odradek).

When you are in BTs territory it will automatically point to the closest BT around. It will also start clapping more the closer you get to any BT.

When you activate actual scan, it will show BTs for short period of time.

However, Odradek will stop working if your BB is too stressed. Also, there will be some story related events when you can't use it.

Also, you are supposed to move slowly in BTs zone, otherwise they will detect you right away.